# Push Pull Output and Input Resistances

Tags: amplifier, push-pull, small-signal

I'm reading Sedra's book on Microelectronics (7th edition, section 12.4.2), and in the chapter on Output Stages he calculates the Output Resistance of a Class AB Push Pull Amplifier. My problem is: he uses small-signal parameters to calculate it, but when we are analyzing the output stage, aren't the signals large? Why do we use small signal parameters to calculate the output resistance of an amplifier that deals with large signals?

Comment: If BJTs, the output impedance varies with the output current into the load. So the output impedance may vary a great deal depending on just how the AB output stage's quiescent current is set. I've no idea how *Sedra's book* does all this because I've not used, nor read, Sedra's book(s). You might explain here to help those of us who aren't looking at the book you are. But if this is based on the quiescent point, then you are computing a 'worst case' situation. Depending on where that is relative to some spec'd output, that may be close enough for the need.

Comment: Please list the page and edition, or section.

Comment: If you do not have any external resistance load (or passive internal load devices), then the only remaining output resistance will be a function of small signal parameters of the circuitry (which have dependency on specific large signal operating points). And you need those values, when calculating important properties like gain, gain-bandwith, etc.

Comment: Ohm's law is linear, so if you're calculating a resistance, you're in the "small signal" domain. Whether collapsing the information in the V-I curve into a single number is useful depends on the situation.

Answer (score 3):

Small signal parameters are basically the linearization of the characteristics about the bias (or operating) point. How good or accurate they are in the real world depends on the span over which the linear approximation holds.

If you have an amplifier with an emitter follower output, and the signal is so large that the device's current changes significantly, then there is no single bias or operating point to linearize around -- any calculations will be a significant approximation.

Answer (score 3):

The **open-loop** small-signal resistance is given as the expression \$r_{eN} || r_{eP} = \frac{V_T}{i_n} || \frac{V_T}{i_p}\$. For common split-rail realizations, that value is essentially a worst-case estimate at the midpoint (at which no current is delivered to the load) because \$i_n\$ and \$i_p\$ have essentially equal magnitudes. As either of the currents increases, the small-signal resistance term is dominated by that corresponding current dropping, of course departing from our initial calculation.

Furthermore, we can benefit from the fact that feedback (as used in practical realizations of audio amplifier circuits) *linearizes* the circuit, thus partially insulating us from the effect of the variable output resistance above. In either shunt-shunt or series-shunt feedback, the output voltage is sampled and fed back to the gain stage, thus correcting for the non-linear loading effects on the output.